# How to loop range of cells faster and smaller

Tags: excel, vba

Currently this is taking around 30 mins to finish as the if conditions are checking 25000+ rows and 168 columns. This is just one function and I need to make around 10 more of such functions, so it will take a lot of time for the program to finish. Is there any way I can make this faster and simpler. Any help will be appreciated.. thanks

```vb
Sub SumBasicPay()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim total As Double
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
        
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
    
    
    Worksheets("Database").Activate
    LastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    
     For iRow = 2 To LastRow
         total = 0
         For iCol = 17 To 168
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A7") And Sheet12.Range("B7") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A7") And Sheet12.Range("B7") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A8") And Sheet12.Range("B8") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A8") And Sheet12.Range("B8") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A9") And Sheet12.Range("B9") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A9") And Sheet12.Range("B9") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A10") And Sheet12.Range("B10") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A10") And Sheet12.Range("B10") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A11") And Sheet12.Range("B11") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A11") And Sheet12.Range("B11") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A12") And Sheet12.Range("B12") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A12") And Sheet12.Range("B12") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A13") And Sheet12.Range("B13") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A13") And Sheet12.Range("B13") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A14") And Sheet12.Range("B14") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A14") And Sheet12.Range("B14") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A15") And Sheet12.Range("B15") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A15") And Sheet12.Range("B15") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A16") And Sheet12.Range("B16") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A16") And Sheet12.Range("B16") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A17") And Sheet12.Range("B17") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A17") And Sheet12.Range("B17") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A18") And Sheet12.Range("B18") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A18") And Sheet12.Range("B18") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A19") And Sheet12.Range("B19") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A19") And Sheet12.Range("B19") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A20") And Sheet12.Range("B20") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A20") And Sheet12.Range("B20") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A21") And Sheet12.Range("B21") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A21") And Sheet12.Range("B21") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A22") And Sheet12.Range("B22") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A22") And Sheet12.Range("B22") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A23") And Sheet12.Range("B23") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A23") And Sheet12.Range("B23") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A24") And Sheet12.Range("B24") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A24") And Sheet12.Range("B24") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A25") And Sheet12.Range("B25") = "+" Then
                 total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Range("A25") And Sheet12.Range("B25") = "-" Then
                 total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
             End If
             
             
             
         Next iCol            
         ws1.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = total  
     Next iRow

End Sub
```

If any more information is required, please do let me know.

> Edit : Thanks for the answer @WojciechWojtulewski. Below is the updated code now after modifications which is taking 10 mins to complete instead of 25 mins.

```vb
Sub SumBasicPay()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim total As Double
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
        
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
        
                
    Worksheets("Database").Activate
    LastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow
     total = 0
     For iCol = 17 To 168
        For abc = 7 To 25
            If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Cells(abc, 1).Value And Sheet12.Cells(abc, 2) = "+" Then
                total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
            ElseIf Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Cells(abc, 1).Value And Sheet12.Cells(abc, 2) = "-" Then
                total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
            End If
         Next
     Next iCol
     ws1.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = total
 Next iRow

End Sub
```

> If anyone can provide the array method that takes less time to complete, that will be much appreciated

Comment: 1) process them in array. 2) instead of having 2 If statements per row, make a loop from 7 to 25 and compare `If Cells(1,iCol).Value = Sheet12.Cells(n,1) Then`. If its true then you check `If Sheet12.Cells(n,2) = "+"` and `If Sheet12.Cells(n,2) = "-"` (or if its me, I'll make it into a Select statement). You can do this in array as well (as mentioned in pt 1)

Comment: Or instead of  loop from 7 to 25, you can alternatively do a `Find`, matching `Cells(1,iCol).Value`.

Comment: @RaymondWu, thanks for the prompt response, I in-fact tried the array method but could not achieve the desired result and was getting errors, will it be possible for you to maybe share an example of your solution and I will try and replicate it.

Comment: Why don't you share what you tried and see what is not working with it? I'm not with my computer now so I can only try it around 12 hours away from now. (Someone is definitely around now and they are expert so you can try your luck and wait it out). @BinaryBytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Sum Up By Using Arrays

**The Final Solution**

- This takes 3+ seconds for all of your data. BTW, Columns 8 and 9 don't find the strings.
- Whenever you see constants at the beginning of a code, be sure that these constants can be used as arguments.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumUpAll()

    Dim dTime As Double: dTime = Timer ' start measuring the time passed

    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 10
        SumUp 2 * n - 1, 2 * n, n
    Next n

    Debug.Print Timer - dTime ' end measuring and print the time passed

    MsgBox "Data summed up.", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub SumUp( _
        ByVal MatchColumn As Long, _
        ByVal OperatorColumn As Long, _
        ByVal DestinationColumn As Long)
    
    'Dim dTime As Double: dTime = Timer ' start measuring the time passed
    
    ' Source
    Const sfRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    Const sfCol As Long = 10 ' First Column
    Const slCol As Long = 168 ' Last Column
    ' Lookup
    Const lfRow As Long = 7 ' First Row
    ' Destination
    Const dfRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Database")
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    If srg.Columns.Count < slCol Then Exit Sub ' not enough columns
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1 ' without headers
    If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    
    Dim scOffset As Long: scOffset = sfCol - 1
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = slCol - scOffset
    
    Dim shrg As Range ' source headers
    Set shrg = srg.Rows(1).Resize(, scCount).Offset(, scOffset)
    
    ' Lookup
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = Sheet12
    ' or:
    'Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets("Run")
    Dim lfCell As Range: Set lfCell = lws.Cells(lfRow, MatchColumn)
    Dim llCell As Range
    Set llCell = lws.Cells(lws.Rows.Count, MatchColumn).End(xlUp)
    
    Dim lrCount As Long: lrCount = llCell.Row - lfRow + 1
    If lrCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data in Last Row Column
    
    Dim lcCount As Long: lcCount = Application.Max(MatchColumn, OperatorColumn)
    
    ' Lookup Range (from column 'A')
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Cells(lfRow, "A").Resize(lrCount, lcCount)
    
    Dim lmData As Variant ' Match Data ('shrg' column indexes without offset)
    Dim loData As Variant ' Operator Data
    
    If lrCount = 1 Then ' only one row
        ReDim lmData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        lmData(1, 1) = Application.Match( _
            lrg.Columns(MatchColumn).Value, shrg, 0)
        ReDim loData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        loData(1, 1) = lrg.Columns(OperatorColumn).Value
    Else ' multiple rows
        lmData = Application.Match(lrg.Columns(MatchColumn), shrg, 0) ' matches
        loData = lrg.Columns(OperatorColumn).Value ' operators
    End If
    
    ' A jagged array that will be containing the arrays of the values of
    ' the source columns defined by the 'lmData' indexes increased by 'scCount'.
    Dim sData As Variant: ReDim sData(1 To lrCount) ' Source Array
    
    ' A dictionary to hold the column indexes (no error values)
    ' and their associated operators.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case i.e. A = a
    
    ' For...Next Loop Additional Variables
    Dim scIndex As Long ' Source Column Index
    Dim lr As Long ' Match/Operator Arrays Rows Counter
    Dim sn As Long ' Source Array Elements (Arrays) Counter
    
    ' Write to Source Array and to the dictionary.
    For lr = 1 To lrCount
        If IsNumeric(lmData(lr, 1)) Then ' match found
            scIndex = lmData(lr, 1) + scOffset ' increase by offset
            If Not dict.Exists(scIndex) Then ' match doesn't exist
                dict(scIndex) = loData(lr, 1) '
                sn = sn + 1
                sData(sn) = srg.Columns(scIndex) _
                    .Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value ' without headers
            'Else ' match exists: duplicate in match column (keep the previous)
            End If
        'Else ' match not found (error value)
        End If
    Next lr
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' The relevant data is in 'sData' and 'dict'.
    Erase lmData
    Erase loData
    
    If sn < lrCount Then ' found error values in 'lmData'
        ReDim Preserve sData(1 To sn)
    'Else ' no error values found in 'lmData'
    End If
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dfRow, DestinationColumn)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(rCount)
    Dim dData() As Double: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1) ' Destination Array
    
    ' For...Next Loop Additional Variables
    Dim sMatch As Variant ' current value in current array of Source Array
    Dim Key As Variant ' to loop through the dictionary
    Dim r As Long ' Source/Destination Rows Counter
    Dim dTotal As Double
    
    ' Write totals ('dTotal') to Destination Array.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        dTotal = 0
        sn = 0 ' Source Array Elements (Arrays) Counter
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            sn = sn + 1
            sMatch = sData(sn)(r, 1)
            If IsNumeric(sMatch) Then ' sMatch is numeric
                Select Case dict(Key)
                Case "+"
                    dTotal = dTotal + sMatch
                Case "-"
                    dTotal = dTotal - sMatch
                'Case Else ' neither '+' nor '-' (do nothing)
                End Select
            'Else ' sMatch is not numeric
            End If
        Next Key
        dData(r, 1) = dTotal
    Next r

    ' Write
    drg.Value = dData
    
    'Debug.Print Timer - dTime ' end measuring and print the time passed
    
End Sub
```

**The Previous Improvement**

- Not accounted for if there is one row in Lookup and if no match at all.
- This takes less than half a second on my machine. I've accidentally noticed that just to write the complete range to an array (25,000+ rows and 150+ columns), it takes `1.5` seconds. So I just couldn't let it go.
- This will use `Application.Match` on the first relevant row range of the `Source` using the 'match' column in `Lookup` resulting in an array of matching indexes (and possible error values (not in this case though)). FYI, the `SO` contributor T.M. has done some extensive research on this behavior of `Applicaion.Match`.
- These indexes (increased by an offset) will be used to write only the relevant column ranges to a jagged array (an array of arrays) which are in this case few (9) and will use a dictionary to hold the indexes and the associated operators (`+/-`) (also illustrated in Raymond Wu's answer).
- I'm not sure how the efficiency will decrease for many more matching columns.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumBasicPay()
    
    Dim dTime As Double: dTime = Timer ' start measuring the time passed
    
    ' Source
    Const sfRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    Const sfCol As Long = 17 ' First Column
    Const slCol As Long = 168 ' Last Column
    ' Lookup
    Const lfRow As Long = 7 ' First Row
    Const llrCol As Long = 1 ' Last Row Column
    Const lmCol As Long = 1 ' Match Column
    Const loCol As Long = 2 ' Operator Column
    ' Destination
    Const dFirst As String = "A2" ' First Cell Address
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Database")
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    If srg.Columns.Count < slCol Then Exit Sub ' not enough columns
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1 ' without headers
    If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    
    Dim scOffset As Long: scOffset = sfCol - 1
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = slCol - scOffset
    
    Dim shrg As Range ' source headers
    Set shrg = srg.Rows(1).Resize(, scCount).Offset(, scOffset)
    
    ' Lookup
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = Sheet12
    ' or:
    'Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets("Run")
    Dim lfCell As Range: Set lfCell = lws.Cells(lfRow, llrCol)
    Dim llCell As Range
    Set llCell = lws.Cells(lws.Rows.Count, llrCol).End(xlUp)
    
    Dim lrCount As Long: lrCount = llCell.Row - lfRow + 1
    If lrCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data in Last Row Column
    
    Dim lcCount As Long: lcCount = Application.Max(lmCol, loCol)
    
    ' Lookup Range (from column 'A')
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Cells(lfRow, "A").Resize(lrCount, lcCount)
    
    Dim lmData As Variant ' Match Data ('shrg' column indexes without offset)
    lmData = Application.Match(lrg.Columns(lmCol), shrg, 0) ' ignores case
    Dim loData As Variant: loData = lrg.Columns(loCol).Value ' operators
    
    ' A jagged array that will be containing the arrays of the values of
    ' the source columns defined by the 'lmData' indexes increased by 'scCount'.
    Dim sData As Variant: ReDim sData(1 To lrCount) ' Source Array
    
    ' A dictionary to hold the column indexes (no error values)
    ' and their associated operators.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case i.e. A = a
    
    ' For...Next Loop Additional Variables
    Dim scIndex As Long ' Source Column Index
    Dim lr As Long ' Match/Operator Arrays Rows Counter
    Dim sn As Long ' Source Array Elements (Arrays) Counter
    
    ' Write to Source Array and to the dictionary.
    For lr = 1 To lrCount
        If IsNumeric(lmData(lr, 1)) Then ' match found
            scIndex = lmData(lr, 1) + scOffset ' increase by offset
            If Not dict.Exists(scIndex) Then ' match doesn't exist
                dict(scIndex) = loData(lr, 1) '
                sn = sn + 1
                sData(sn) = srg.Columns(scIndex) _
                    .Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value ' without headers
            'Else ' match exists: duplicate in match column (keep the previous)
            End If
        'Else ' match not found (error value)
        End If
    Next lr
    
    ' The relevant data is in 'sData' and 'dict'.
    Erase lmData
    Erase loData
    
    If sn < lrCount Then ' found error values in 'lmData'
        ReDim Preserve sData(1 To sn)
    'Else ' no error values found in 'lmData'
    End If
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(rCount)
    Dim dData() As Double: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1) ' Destination Array
    
    ' For...Next Loop Additional Variables
    Dim sMatch As Variant ' current value in current array of Source Array
    Dim Key As Variant ' to loop through the dictionary
    Dim r As Long ' Source/Destination Rows Counter
    Dim dTotal As Double
    
    ' Write totals ('dTotal') to Destination Array.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        dTotal = 0
        sn = 0 ' Source Array Elements (Arrays) Counter
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            sn = sn + 1
            sMatch = sData(sn)(r, 1)
            If IsNumeric(sMatch) Then ' sMatch is numeric
                Select Case dict(Key)
                Case "+"
                    dTotal = dTotal + sMatch
                Case "-"
                    dTotal = dTotal - sMatch
                'Case Else ' neither '+' nor '-' (do nothing)
                End Select
            'Else ' sMatch is not numeric
            End If
        Next Key
        dData(r, 1) = dTotal
    Next r

    ' Write
    drg.Value = dData
    
    Debug.Print Timer - dTime ' end measuring and print the time passed
    
    MsgBox "Summed up Basic Pay.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

**Previous Solution**

- This took between 20 and 25 seconds for 50,000 records (rows) on my machine.
- I'm leaving this here because the superior solution might become much slower (not tested) for many more columns.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumBasicPay()
    
    Dim dTime As Double: dTime = Timer ' start measuring the time passed
    
    ' Source
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const sfCol As Long = 17
    Const slCol As Long = 168
    ' Lookup
    Const lfRow As Long = 7
    Const lfCol As Long = 1
    Const lCols As Long = 2 ' fixed
    ' Destination
    Const dFirst As String = "A2"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Database")
    Dim strg As Range: Set strg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    If strg.Columns.Count < slCol Then Exit Sub ' not enough columns
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = strg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = slCol - sfCol + 1
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sws.Columns(sfCol).Resize(, scCount)
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(strg, scrg)
    
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Lookup
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = Sheet12
    ' or:
    'Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets("Run")
    Dim lfCell As Range: Set lfCell = lws.Cells(lfRow, lfCol)
    Dim llCell As Range: Set llCell = lws.Cells(lws.Rows.Count, lfCol).End(xlUp)
    Dim lrCount As Long: lrCount = llCell.Row - lfCell.Row + 1
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range(llCell, lfCell).Resize(, lCols)
    Dim lData As Variant: lData = lrg.Value
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srCount - 1
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount)
    Dim dData() As Double: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' For...Next Loop Additional Variables
    Dim sLookup As String
    Dim sMatch As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim sc As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim dTotal As Double
    
    ' dTotal
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        dTotal = 0
        For sc = 1 To scCount
            sLookup = CStr(sData(1, sc)) ' the string in the first row
            sMatch = sData(sr, sc) ' the value in the current row
            If IsNumeric(sMatch) Then ' match is a number
                For lr = 1 To lrCount
                    If CStr(lData(lr, 1)) = sLookup Then ' lookup is equal
                        Select Case CStr(lData(lr, 2))
                        Case "+"
                            dTotal = dTotal + sMatch
                        Case "-"
                            dTotal = dTotal - sMatch
                        'Case Else ' neither '+' nor '-' (do nothing)
                        End Select
                    'Else ' lookup is not equal (do nothing)
                    End If
                Next lr
            'Else ' match is not a number
            End If
        Next sc
        dData(sr - 1, 1) = dTotal
    Next sr

    ' Write
    drg.Value = dData
    
    Debug.Print Timer - dTime ' end measuring and print the time passed
    
    MsgBox "Summed up Basic Pay.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution however for some reason I am getting all row values as 0

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Will fix it ASAP.

Comment: will be looking forward to it.

Comment: It took a while, but it's even faster now (as expected).

Comment: Yes It's much faster now however it's still showing 0 as all row values and #NA as last row value.

Comment: This change only covers the last #NA value (see `drCount`). Here's my logic: Loop through rows of Source from row 2 to last row, loop through columns of Source. Check the value in the first row against each value in Lookup Column1. If it's a match, check +- in Lookup Column 2. Add/subtract the value of the current row and current column of Source to Total. Can you see what's wrong with my logic? BTW, your updated code shows the same results on my end. I am using whole numbers. If you have many decimals, that could be the reason that it cannot find a match. Could you send your file to my email?

Comment: The logic seems correct and I have edited the question so you can download the excel file for reference.

Comment: I got it. Now it takes 12 seconds with your data. The mistake was that I was using numbers for the first row of Source and the first column of Lookup. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks...Working well for "BasicPay", I now have the option to incorporate your's or Raymond's solution and will look into it to understand and replicate this for the other functions...i.e. "NightDifferential" etc.

Comment: Thanks this is very efficient. I am not very well versed with arrays and dictionary concepts, so what all references have to be changed for other columns such as "Night Differential Wages" etc. I tried changing the match column and operator column to replicate the logic on night differential wages but it didn't work that way. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the final answer. It will help me a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

I save the operator to be used for each column using Dictionary so that we can avoid unnecessary check for the same thing in the main loop.

The main loop through the database is roughly the same, with the changes being using the Dictionary to get the operator and do the math, skipping the need to loop through each category for a match again.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumBasicPay()
    Const dbHeaderRow As Long = 1
    Const dbStartRow As Long = 2
    Const dbStartCol As Long = 17
    Const dbLastCol As Long = 168
    
    Const matchStartRow As Long = 7
    Const matchHeaderCol As Long = 1
    Const matchOperatorCol As Long = 2
        
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet
    Set wsDB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    
    Dim dbLastRow As Long
    dbLastRow = wsDB.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    
    Dim inputArr As Variant
    inputArr = wsDB.Range(wsDB.Cells(dbHeaderRow, dbStartCol), wsDB.Cells(dbLastRow, dbLastCol)).Value
    
    Dim matchLastRow As Long
    matchLastRow = Sheet12.Cells(Sheet12.Rows.Count, matchHeaderCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim matchArr As Variant
    matchArr = Sheet12.Range(Sheet12.Cells(matchStartRow, matchHeaderCol), Sheet12.Cells(matchLastRow, matchOperatorCol)).Value
    Dim matchDict As Object
    Set matchDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim matchRow As Long
    
    'Use Dictionary to assign the + - operator to each column (so we don't need to keep checking when looping through the rows)
    For iCol = 1 To UBound(inputArr, 2)
        For matchRow = 1 To UBound(matchArr, 1)
            If inputArr(dbHeaderRow, iCol) = matchArr(matchRow, 1) Then
                matchDict.Add iCol, matchArr(matchRow, 2)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next matchRow
    Next iCol
    
    Dim outputArr() As Double
    ReDim outputArr(1 To 1 + (dbLastRow - dbStartRow), 1 To 1) As Double
    
    Dim total As Double
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    'Loop through rows
    For iRow = 2 To UBound(inputArr, 1)
        total = 0
        
        'Then the columns
        For iCol = 1 To UBound(inputArr, 2)
            'Get the operator from the dictionary and do the math
            If matchDict.Exists(iCol) Then
                Select Case matchDict(iCol)
                    Case "+": total = total + inputArr(iRow, iCol)
                    Case "-": total = total - inputArr(iRow, iCol)
                End Select
            End If
        Next iCol
            
        'Output total to the output array
        Dim outputIndex As Long
        outputIndex = outputIndex + 1
        outputArr(outputIndex, 1) = total
    Next iRow
                
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
    
    'Write the output into worksheet Main
    wsOutput.Cells(dbStartRow, 1).Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1)).Value = outputArr
    wsOutput.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: if you are going to advocate `.Find`  you really should be aware of its default settings,  [specifically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)  _The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used_

Comment: @chrisneilsen fair point - will edit to specify all arguments

Comment: @RaymondWu. Thanks for the solution however for some reason I am getting all row values as 0. I have edited the question so you can download the excel file for reference.

Comment: @BinaryBytes In `Run` worksheet, why do I see categories only from `A7:A15`? Your original code have all the `If..Else` up till `A25`. Is that intended?

Comment: @RaymondWu, Yes the additional range is intentional to accommodate new codes in future.

Comment: @BinaryBytes In that case, I have edited that part so that it will retrieve up to the last used row so you can add in as many new code as you want without the need to modify the code (as long the category is in col A and operator in col B)

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks for the answer... but I am getting compile error as "Variable not defined" (matchfirstrow) and when I define it, It shows a runtime error. Also the basic pay total value should come as **_239,981,905.60_** however with your solution the basic pay total value is not matching.

Comment: @BinaryBytes Sorry I had a typo there, that should be `matchStartRow`. As for the total value. It's difficult for me to find out what is wrong so you have to match a few incorrect row and breakdown the calculation of the correct value for comparison (are the correct value in the file?)

Comment: @BinaryBytes I have edited the matching part to exact match instead, can you try it out?

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks, the code is now giving the correct calculation for BasicPay and working fine. The same logic has to be applied for "Night Differential", "Overtime" , "Attendance Bounus", "Bounus", "Holiday".....etc

Comment: @BinaryBytes Not to be rude but you are changing your goal post here since that wasn't part of the question. I'm off the computer so you have to wait till at least tomorrow for me to try anything. If you understand the concept of adding the operator then give a try to incorporate the same logic, just to different range. Or if you are lazy then just move all those categories to column A & B as well.

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks Raymond, you have been very helpful. Never meant to divert. The logic is still the same for all functions and wanted to test it out on one and replicate then. I will not bother you any further. Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question to follow up if you are stuck @BinaryBytes

Comment: Superb, never crossed my mind to use the dictionary. It takes less than 5 seconds compared to 12 seconds of my latest edition. In my defense, it was a struggle.

Answer (score -4):

```
For iRow = 2 To LastRow
     total = 0
     For iCol = 17 To 168
        For iRow = 7 To 25
            If Cells(1, iCol).Value = Sheet12.Celss(iRow, 1).Value And Sheet12.Cells(iRow, 2) = "+" Then
                total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
            Else
                total = total - Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
            End If
         Next
     Next iCol
     ws1.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = total
 Next iRow
```

Comment: This is NOT a good answer. Do not do this! Use a Variant array. Especially if this is just one of a bunch of different routines that loop through your values. The array solution will be hundreds if not thousands of times faster!

Comment: @BigBen I have just added the updated code that is now taking 10 mins to complete, can you please provide the same with the array solution if that will be a faster method.

Comment: @ExcelHero I have just added the updated code that is now taking 10 mins to complete, can you please provide the same with the array solution if that will be a faster method.